# How to perform mongoexport without "numberLong" objects

Tags: json, mongodb, export

I did a mongoexport dump of a database:

`$ mongoexport -d my_db -c articles`

and I'm seeing some of our ids are wrapped in `"$numberLong"` objects.  Unfortunately, it isn't consistent.  Some `filemakerIds` are just plain ints:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"52126317036480948dc2abf2"},"filemakerId":4129,
```

and some are not:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"52126317036480948dc2abf1"},"filemakerId":{"$numberLong":"4073"},
```

These ids will always be a 3 or 4 digit number.  It would be easier for me if the dump consistently displayed them as an Int ( eg `"filemakerId":4129`).  Can mongoexport force this?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to the mongoexport tool can be MongoCompass where you can export your data in JSON and CSV.

First, go to aggregation console and create an aggregation pipeline.

In **$project** section convert your data into double or int.(i used double)

add this:

```
{$project:{"filemakerId":{$toDouble:"$filemakerId"}}}
```

By converting you data to double/int you will didn't get the "filemakerId":{"$numberLong":"4073"}.
what you will get "filemakerId":4073

Finally, click on export and choose the output format which would be JSON/CSV.
Hope you'll get your expected result.